# xpath inside loop does not locate properly

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

i have a code snippet where I go to [url](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&fs=true&qid=1665559431&rnid=8622845011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_5&ds=v1%3AgAO0%2BZc%2BC6RthRkqyWzOHmDVufv7JbuCK96Grvjle68), to scrape data by blocks of div elements.
I am easily locating div bocks by different `data-asin` numbers. And inside loop `locator` changes accordingly.
then strangely, `x_block_of_index=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator)` works well, i mean according to new data-asin number finds appropriate block but afterwards, `y_title=x_block_of_index.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div/h2/a/span')` finds only first div block text value. Does not change according loop. I tried many ways, to get why, as you will see i tried to get attribute of span element, as it is DOM property of HTML element

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=77)

try:
    x_indexes=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@data-asin]')))
    print(len(x_indexes),'X_INDEX')

    counter=1
    for i in range(len(x_indexes)):
        x_data_asin=x_indexes[i].get_attribute('data-asin')
        if x_data_asin!="":
            print(x_data_asin,i,counter)
            counter+=1

            #locating title
            locator='//div[@data-asin="'+x_data_asin+'"]'
            x_block_of_index=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator)
            x_title=x_indexes[i].find_element(By.XPATH,'//div/h2/a/span')
            #print(x_block_of_index.text)
            y_title=x_block_of_index.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div/h2/a/span')
            print(y_title.text)
            print(y_title.get_attribute('textContent'))

except:
    y_indexes=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@data-asin]')
    print(len(y_indexes))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add a dot `.` at the beginning of the XPath to make it relative.
I mean instead of `x_title=x_indexes[i].find_element(By.XPATH,'//div/h2/a/span')` probably it should be `x_title=x_indexes[i].find_element(By.XPATH,'.//div/h2/a/span')`
The same about `y_title=x_block_of_index.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div/h2/a/span')` -> change it to be `y_title=x_block_of_index.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//div/h2/a/span')`.
When you apply XPath locator, driver will start searching from the DOM upper element and it will return the first match. But when you put a dot `.` before the XPath expression and apply it on some specific element (node) it will start searching form (inside) that specific element (node)

Comment: I am trying now I 'll let you know. I actually thought and added `..` it is abs path. But, then did not try relative path. Let' s see. But it is so strange, I think it is due do try except. Now I am trying to get all of asins value inside List......YOU ARE GENIUS :)! worked

Comment: No, I'm no genius. Just somewhat experienced :)

Comment: @Prophet - nice explanation, learned a new thing.

Comment: @AbiSaran this is what this platform for 